# Displaying upvotes on different models together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have upvotes working on posts and comments using the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem. I display the posts and comments a user has upvoted like this:

```
@upvoted_posts = @user.get_voted Post
@upvoted_comments = @user.get_voted Comment
```

Is there a way that I can show the upvoted posts and comments together in one feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this in `user.rb` if `user has_many :posts`

```
def all_post_liked_by_others
  @posts = Array.new
  if self.posts.present?
    self.posts.reload.includes(:votes).each do |p| 
    if p.likes.count > 0
        @posts << p
    end    
  end
  return @posts.compact.flatten.uniq
else
return @posts.compact.flatten.uniq

end
end##method ends
```

Similarly you can define a method for comments and then merge them together...